# JQUERY: Hide item with click and hover

Tags: jquery, list, hover, click, hidden

I need to select the first item in the first list and hide the element. After hiding the first elements of the list when the mouse passes over.

How I can synchronize the two events?

```
$( "dt" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).slideUp(500);
});
$( "dd" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).delay(2000).slideUp(500);
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<dl>
  <dt>list</dt>
  <dd>one</dd>
  <dd>two</dd>
  <dd>three</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You can only create the `hover` event after the click.

```js
$( "#first" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).delay(2000).slideUp(500);
    
     $( "dt" ).hover(function() {
         $(this).siblings("dd").hide();
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<dl>
    <dt>list</dt>
    <dd id="first">one</dd>
    <dd>two</dd>
    <dd>three</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Sorry, I me wrong. What I need is after hiding the first list item '<dd> one </ dd>' to click is to hide the rest of '<dd>' when the mouse is over '<dt> list </ dt>'.

Comment: I do not know if I explain

Comment: No, I don't think I understand you. If you hover `dd` you want that to hide. And if you click on `dt`, you want all the `dd` to hide?

Comment: First click on `<dd> one </ dd>` and disappears.
After the pointer over `<dt> list </ dt>` disappears other `dd`

Comment: Only the first click should work? Clicking `<dd>two</dd>` should do anything?

Comment: Only first click of `dd` the others `dd` no. The rest of `dd` disappear when the pointer is over `dt`

Comment: @us3r Edited my answer. I hope that's what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much , was just that. Sorry about the mess .